File encryption when downloaded from GCS using nodejs
I'm developing a files sharing app where one can easily upload and download files. The uploaded files are stored in a bucket on google cloud storage while the metadata are stored on atlas. The files downloaded from gcs are encrypted with a '.txt' extension which is different from the inital uploaded files. I don't why this is happening, I checked the files on my bucket and they are in the right format but encrypted when downloaded.
Here is a my code :
app.get('/download/:id', async (req, res) => { 

    const { id } = req.params; 
  
    try {
        // Find doc by id and get the fileName
        const document = await Document.findById(id);

        if (!document || !document.fileName) {
        return res.status(404).send('File not found');
        }
        const fileName = document.fileName;
        const type = document.fileType;
        console.log(type)
        const [file] = await bucket.file(fileName).download();

        // Set header for file download
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', type);
        // Send file as a response
        res.send(file);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading the file:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error downloading the file');
    }
});


